# Use Angular 9 library from Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular9, angular-library, angular10

I will be migrating our Angular component library from Angular 8 to Angular 9 or 10.  Most of our applications are written in Angular 8.  Will our Angular 8 apps to be able to use versions of the component library which were built with Angular 9/10?  Assuming the component library does not use any new APIs introduced in Angular 9.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I just did migrate from Angular 6 to 9 recently without any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the angular component library and your applications angular version in sync, by this practice you will less angular breaking changes and your will be able to use latest feature in your application